# Build project on CentOS using travis?

Tags: centos, travis-ci

I'd like to use travis to build my project, I noticed that it build on Ubuntu, I was wondering if it is possible to build using a CentOS VM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run tests on CentOS 7 with Travis-CI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535195/how-to-run-tests-on-centos-7-with-travis-ci)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  You can build and run your tests on CentOS by using Docker.

See the answer to this question for an example .travis.yml:

[How to run tests on CentOS 7 with Travis-CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535195/how-to-run-tests-on-centos-7-with-travis-ci)

Answer (score 1):

You can build travis-ci and travis-build locally to run against your code. This way it can run on CentOS and RHEL. (I have tested this.)

The problem is the build servers are created using travis-cookbooks and they do not currently support RHEL / CentOS. So the hosted version of travis-ci will not work with Fedora / CentOS / RHEL until this package is modified to support them.