# How to run tests on CentOS 7 with Travis-CI?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I try to use [Travis-CI to test my ansible playbooks on CentOS 7](https://github.com/weldpua2008/ansible-apache/blob/fe6e77d5d389ed6005a7b90e0b15a8752609cbdc/.travis.yml).

I got an error: 
[error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/suexec: cpio: cap_set_file.](https://travis-ci.org/weldpua2008/ansible-apache/jobs/79907720#L58)

Also I installed docker with:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

on my Ubuntu:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

But there is this error:

```
#docker run --rm=true -ti centos:7 /bin/bash
[root@08bf52d53465 /]#
[root@ca03cf7a13e2 /]# yum install httpd -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                                                                  | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                                | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                               | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
(1/4): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                     |  74 kB  00:00:00
(2/4): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                         | 154 kB  00:00:01
(3/4): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                    | 3.3 MB  00:00:06
(4/4): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                       | 5.1 MB  00:00:06
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.nonstop.co.il
 * extras: centos.joinweb.co.il
 * updates: centos.joinweb.co.il
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1 for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: system-logos >= 7.92.1-1 for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/mime.types for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaprutil-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.4.8-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package apr-util.x86_64 0:1.5.2-6.el7 will be installed
---> Package centos-logos.noarch 0:70.0.6-2.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1 will be installed
---> Package mailcap.noarch 0:2.1.41-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================
 Package                       Arch                    Version                                Repository                Size
=============================================================================================================================
Installing:
 httpd                         x86_64                  2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1                  updates                  2.7 M
Installing for dependencies:
 apr                           x86_64                  1.4.8-3.el7                            base                     103 k
 apr-util                      x86_64                  1.5.2-6.el7                            base                      92 k
 centos-logos                  noarch                  70.0.6-2.el7.centos                    updates                   21 M
 httpd-tools                   x86_64                  2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1                  updates                   79 k
 mailcap                       noarch                  2.1.41-2.el7                           base                      31 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+5 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 24 M
Installed size: 32 M
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/packages/apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(1/6): apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                     | 103 kB  00:00:00
(2/6): mailcap-2.1.41-2.el7.noarch.rpm                                                                |  31 kB  00:00:00
(3/6): apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                |  92 kB  00:00:00
Public key for httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm is not installed               ] 559 kB/s | 764 kB  00:00:43 ETA
(4/6): httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm                                                   |  79 kB  00:00:01
(5/6): httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm                                                         | 2.7 MB  00:00:03
(6/6): centos-logos-70.0.6-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm                                                    |  21 MB  00:00:16
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                        1.5 MB/s |  24 MB  00:00:16
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Importing GPG key 0xF4A80EB5:
 Userid     : "CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>"
 Fingerprint: 6341 ab27 53d7 8a78 a7c2 7bb1 24c6 a8a7 f4a8 0eb5
 Package    : centos-release-7-1.1503.el7.centos.2.8.x86_64 (@CentOS)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64                                                                                    1/6
  Installing : apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64                                                                               2/6
  Installing : httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64                                                                  3/6
  Installing : mailcap-2.1.41-2.el7.noarch                                                                               4/6
  Installing : centos-logos-70.0.6-2.el7.centos.noarch                                                                   5/6
  Installing : httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64                                                                        6/6
Error unpacking rpm package httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/suexec: cpio: cap_set_file
error: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64: install failed
  Verifying  : centos-logos-70.0.6-2.el7.centos.noarch                                                                   1/6
  Verifying  : apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64                                                                                    2/6
  Verifying  : mailcap-2.1.41-2.el7.noarch                                                                               3/6
  Verifying  : apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64                                                                               4/6
  Verifying  : httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64                                                                  5/6
  Verifying  : httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64                                                                        6/6

Dependency Installed:
  apr.x86_64 0:1.4.8-3.el7                      apr-util.x86_64 0:1.5.2-6.el7    centos-logos.noarch 0:70.0.6-2.el7.centos
  httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1    mailcap.noarch 0:2.1.41-2.el7

Failed:
  httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1

Complete!
[root@ca03cf7a13e2 /]#
```

I created "special" docker image that includes an Ansible https://github.com/weldpua2008/docker-ansible/blob/ansible_1.9.2/centos/7/Dockerfile

Is there any possibilities to run tests of ansible playbook on CentOS 7?

So I updated /etc/default/docker with:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-s devicemapper"
```

restarted docker:
    service docker restart

## docker run --rm=true -ti   centos:7  /bin/bash

```
[root@16702cbf3f2c /]# yum install -y httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                                                                  | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                                | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
systemdcontainer                                                                                      | 1.9 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                               | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
(1/4): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                         | 154 kB  00:00:03
(2/4): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                     |  74 kB  00:00:04
(3/4): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                    | 3.3 MB  00:01:10
(4/4): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                       | 5.1 MB  00:01:22
systemdcontainer/primary_db                                                                           |  20 kB  00:00:01
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos.syn.co.il
 * extras: centos.syn.co.il
 * updates: centos.syn.co.il
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1 for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: system-logos >= 7.92.1-1 for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/mime.types for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaprutil-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.4.8-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package apr-util.x86_64 0:1.5.2-6.el7 will be installed
---> Package centos-logos.noarch 0:70.0.6-2.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1 will be installed
---> Package mailcap.noarch 0:2.1.41-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================
 Package                       Arch                    Version                                Repository                Size
=============================================================================================================================
Installing:
 httpd                         x86_64                  2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1                  updates                  2.7 M
Installing for dependencies:
 apr                           x86_64                  1.4.8-3.el7                            base                     103 k
 apr-util                      x86_64                  1.5.2-6.el7                            base                      92 k
 centos-logos                  noarch                  70.0.6-2.el7.centos                    updates                   21 M
 httpd-tools                   x86_64                  2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1                  updates                   79 k
 mailcap                       noarch                  2.1.41-2.el7                           base                      31 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+5 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 24 M
Installed size: 32 M
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates/packages/httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(1/6): httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm                                                   |  79 kB  00:00:03
Public key for apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(2/6): apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                |  92 kB  00:00:04
(3/6): mailcap-2.1.41-2.el7.noarch.rpm                                                                |  31 kB  00:00:02
(4/6): apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                     | 103 kB  00:00:06
(5/6): httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm                                                         | 2.7 MB  00:00:52
(6/6): centos-logos-70.0.6-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm                                                    |  21 MB  00:01:11
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                        349 kB/s |  24 MB  00:01:11
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Importing GPG key 0xF4A80EB5:
 Userid     : "CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>"
 Fingerprint: 6341 ab27 53d7 8a78 a7c2 7bb1 24c6 a8a7 f4a8 0eb5
 Package    : centos-release-7-1.1503.el7.centos.2.8.x86_64 (@CentOS)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64                                                                                    1/6
  Installing : apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64                                                                               2/6
  Installing : httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64                                                                  3/6
  Installing : mailcap-2.1.41-2.el7.noarch                                                                               4/6
  Installing : centos-logos-70.0.6-2.el7.centos.noarch                                                                   5/6
  Installing : httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64                                                                        6/6
  Verifying  : centos-logos-70.0.6-2.el7.centos.noarch                                                                   1/6
  Verifying  : apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64                                                                                    2/6
  Verifying  : mailcap-2.1.41-2.el7.noarch                                                                               3/6
  Verifying  : apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64                                                                               4/6
  Verifying  : httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64                                                                  5/6
  Verifying  : httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64                                                                        6/6

Installed:
  httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1

Dependency Installed:
  apr.x86_64 0:1.4.8-3.el7                      apr-util.x86_64 0:1.5.2-6.el7    centos-logos.noarch 0:70.0.6-2.el7.centos
  httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1    mailcap.noarch 0:2.1.41-2.el7

Complete!
```

If there any possibility to do same on Travis CI. I didn't find in the manual http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/ .

I can't edit docker settings https://travis-ci.org/weldpua2008/ansible-apache/jobs/79963906#L29:

```
$ echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="-s devicemapper"' >> /etc/default/docker; service docker restart
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: /etc/default/docker: Permission denied
/etc/init.d/docker: 38: .: Can't open /etc/default/docker
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of Travis CI Docker bug there is way to use new version of Docker. Thank to Dominic Jodoin from Travis CI team.
.travis.yml:

```
sudo: required
env:
  #matrix:
  - OS_TYPE=centos OS_VERSION=6 ANSIBLE_VERSION=1.9.2

branches:
  only:
  - master
#  - stable

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get upgrade lxc-docker
  - echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -s devicemapper"' | sudo tee /etc/default/docker > /dev/null
  - sudo service docker restart
  - sleep 5
  - sudo docker pull weldpua2008/docker-ansible:${OS_TYPE}${OS_VERSION}_v${ANSIBLE_VERSION}

script:
 # Run tests in Container
 - sudo docker run --rm=true -v `pwd`:/ansible-apache:rw weldpua2008/docker-ansible:${OS_TYPE}${OS_VERSION}_v${ANSIBLE_VERSION} /bin/bash -c "/ansible-apache/tests/test-in-docker-image.sh ${OS_TYPE} ${OS_VERSION} ${ANSIBLE_VERSION}"

notifications:
  email: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Circle CI. It is very similar to Travis CI (integration with github, yaml configuration), but faster. And for it is for free for open source! Here are some docs about docker:

https://circleci.com/docs/docker/

Answer (score 0):

Basic usage to use CentOS on Travis CI is like this.

```
services: docker
...
install: docker build --rm -t sample -f Dockerfile_centos .
script: docker run --rm -t sample
```

You can refer below projects' cases.

- https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2
- https://github.com/junaruga/rpm-py-installer